# Attributes in relation after cross product

Tags: relational-theory

I have a question regarding the resulting attributes in the cross product of two relations in relational algebra...

Generally, the cross product will result in a relation whose attributes is the sum of all the attributes, So number of attributes in `R1 x R2` will be attributes in `R1 + R2`, so `R1(a, b, c) x R2(d, e, f)` → `R(a, b, c, d ,e ,f)`...

But, what happens if `R1` and `R2` have common attributes *(attributes of the same name)*? since a relation can not have duplicate attributes... so what would happen in the case `R1(a, b, c) X R2(a, e, f)`? thanks...

Comment: There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express that relation in algebraic notation you actually need to alias the attribute.

The Cartesian product, by design, does not recognize common attribute names, so much like a single operation doesn't work in a self relation scenario, it's necessary to perform a rename within the notation.

The self join example:

> R( a, b, c );
>
> ≠ R ⋈ R ( a, b, c );

Using rename:

> R( a, b, c );
>
> S = ρ<sub>a/b, b/b<sub>2</sub>, c/c<sub>2</sub></sub> R;
>
> ∴ R ⋈ S ( a, b, c, b<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>2</sub> );

For instance:

> E( EmpID, ManagerID, EmpName );
>
> M = ρ<sub>EmpID/ManagerID, ManagerID/ManagerEmpID, EmpName/ManagerName</sub>
>   E;
>
> ∴ E ⋈ M ( EmpID, ManagerID, EmpName, ManagerEmpID, ManagerName );

The Cartesian product can be expressed using relational algebra in the same way:

> R1( a, b, c );
>
> R2( a, e, f );
>
> ≠ R1 × R2 ( a, b, c, e, f );

So then with rename:

> R1( a, b, c );
>
> R2( a, e, f );
>
> R3 = ρ<sub>a/a<sub>2</sub></sub>R2;
>
> ∴ R1 × R3 ( a, b, c, a<sub>2</sub>, e, f );